# recordset using

Tags: database, asp-classic, recordset

Please think a site that has min. 30.000 visitors daily.
The site was coded with asp using sql 2008

There are so many lines and so many database connections

I use recordset like following

```
set rs=server.createobject.......
set rs2=server.createobject.......
set rs3=server.createobject.......
```

I put these line at the top of the page.
then I use them when I need like;

```
rs.open "select........."
rs.close
```

I use them maybe 3 time for each page.

and, at the bottom of the page I write

```
set rs=nothing
set rs2=nothing
set rs3=nothing
```

---

Now my question is that: **does it cause memory leak or any other problem?**

or should i use like

```
set rs=server.createobject
rs.open
rs.close
set rs=nothing
```

I mean should i create object whenever i need and kill it when i finish with it everytime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better if you create the recordsets as disconnected from the DB (freeing the connection)

```
Dim rs, cmd
Set rs = server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set cmd = server.createobject("ADODB.Command")

' Init the ADO objects  & the stored proc parameters
cmd.ActiveConnection = GetConnectionString()
cmd.CommandText = sqlstmt
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

' Execute the query for readonly
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open cmd, , adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly


' Disconnect the recordset
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing
```

Comment: thank you so much. must i really really use readonly instead of read/write? although i dont need to update, i use 1,3 as cursor

Comment: If you don't need to update, you definitively need to use readonly, if much more lightweight. You can use them the way you want.

Comment: just curious, my way causes any memory leak? could you please give me an article link that says adodb.command's performance features.

Comment: No, yours don't cause memory leaks. It's very hard to create leaks in ASP since after the page is created and send, all the memory is cleared (except session variables and COM objects, of course). I don't have any article, Don't believe me, test it.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, manually getting rid of recordsets and other objects is overly cautious, especially at the end of a page.

VBScript has built-in garbage collection and finalizers. As soon as an object is no longer referenced*, it will be GC'd and its `class_terminate` method called. Thus, if you create a recordset inside a function and do not pass the reference outside the function, then it will be collected and its resources freed at the end of the function when it is no longer referenced. If you place an object in a global variable, then it will still be collected when the script has finished running. You cannot cause a memory leak in this fashion. For this reason, unsetting objects at the end of the script is useless, as they would not survive the end of the script anyway unless you deliberately put them in a longer-lived collection such as `Session` or `Application`.

*VBScript's garbage collection guarantees prompt collection, but since it only counts references, it can be fooled by circular references. Keep this in mind and it shouldn't cause you any trouble.

Generally, if there is an object that you need for a short time, referencing it in a function local variable or as the subject of a with block is the best solution. The only reason to manually unset an object is if a) you have a real, demonstrated need to free up resources and either b1) the object in question is referenced in global scope long after it is needed or b2) the object is part of a circular reference.

Now, in your particular case, it looks like the only resource worth worrying about at all is the database connection. If your database is having trouble keeping up with the load, then terminating connections promptly may help. There are two ways to do this. First, manually unset each recordset when you no longer need it, or manually unset each recordset's connection. Second, use the recordsets or connections in a smaller scope so that they will be taken care of automatically. If all you need is the data, for example, then you can use the `GetRows` method to get the data without the overhead of keeping around the recordset. In my code, I never work with recordsets, commands, or connections directly, but rather use helper functions that take care of the gory ADO details and return the actual data I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you should destroy objects as soon as possible.

That being said, I do most of my pages as you do and have never had any problems